# How to fetch result from websites

Tags: android, fetch, urlfetch

I am trying to built app for student in which student enter roll number and get result from https://web.bisemultan.edu.pk.
How can I fetch please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you own this then you can send an API request to it and receive a response from the website and display it as you wish. if you don't own this website then you can embed this website inside your app webview or chrome custom tab

[image: see image here]